# error al recorrer array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo un problema al recorrer mi arrya me marca indefinido siempre lo e hecho así y nunca me había dado problemas es en MVC

ajax

```
 function cargar_requerido(accion)
{
    var accion = accion;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: "json",
        url: base_url +'ctrl_prueba/cargar_prueba',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("print data");
           console.log(data); // Si lo imprime bien
           if(accion== 'cargar')
           {
           cargar_requerido_prueba(data);
           }
        }
    });
}

function cargar_requeridoprueba(data)
{
    var html = '';
console.log(data);//si lo imprime bien
    console.log(data.length);// imprime 245 registros y deberia de ser 1 registro

    $('#body_table').empty();
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(data[i].fecha_registro);// imprime indefinido

  html+= '<tr><td>'+data[i].fecha_registro+
        '</td><td>'+data[i].dias+
        '</td><td>'+data[i].contacto_nombre+
        '</td><td>'+data[i].modelo+
        '</td></tr>';
    }
    $('#body_table').html(html);
}


[{
    "fecha_registro": "2018-10-08",
    "dias": "1",
    "contacto_nombre": "dfdgfdgdfg",
    "modelo": "\tBr-v Prime Blanco",
}]
```

cuando imprimo el
data.length dice 245

Controlador

```
function cargar_prueba()
    {

        $response = $this->valuaciones->cargar_prueba();
        //print_r($response);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Asi me imprime una sola palabra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade lo que imprime el array

Comment: no la impresión del `length` mas bien la tabla que se genera (si es que se genera) y donde te aparece `undefined`

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar los datos del array?

Comment: if(typeof data[i] === 'undefined' && typeof data[i].fecha_registro=== 'undefined'){
    console.log(data[i]);
}

Comment: Mira con eso para ver si algun elemento del array no tiene ese valor

Comment: haz un console log a la variable data después del ajax y pon el resultado, también pon tu función cargar_prueba que tienes en el php

Comment: Creo que tienes mal la consulta SQL, si solo necesitas un registro y te saca 245, algo debe estar mal en tu php

Comment: jorge bowen - no me imprimio nada asi lo puse dentro del for
if(typeof data[i] === 'undefined' && typeof data[i].fecha_registro=== 'undefined'){ console.log(data[i]);}

Comment: sr1871 imprimi la data y si lo imprime bien si problema si lo pongo fuera del ajax pues me va a marcar como indefinida

Comment: @JuanJose al imprimir `console.log(data);` te imprime un objeto o un string?

Comment: un objeto ya pude solucionar el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más probable es que ese objeto en especial de la posición **i** no tiene esa propiedad.

```
if(data[i].fecha_registro == undefined)
{
   console.log(data[i]);
}
```

Con esto sabrás si las otras propiedades de este objeto tiene valor pero la propiedad **fecha_registro** no.

Comment: lo puse y si hay registro me imprime mi data pero cada letra me la va imprimiendo y si me lo imprime bien por que solo existe 1 registro

Comment: Podrias pasarme una captura de lo que te imprimio ? puede ser que el objeto sea tipo string por eso te imprime un caracter.. por que los strings pues son arreglos de caracter y tu lo estas tomando como un objeto

Comment: ya lo puse arriba

Comment: Converti el Json que te regresa a objeto. intenta con esto:

Comment: `function cargar_requeridoprueba(data)
{
    var html = '';
console.log(data);//si lo imprime bien
    console.log(data.length);// imprime 245 registros y deberia de ser 1 registro
    var resp = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#body_table').empty();
    for(var i=0; i<resp.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(resp[i].fecha_registro);// imprime indefinido

  html+= '<tr><td>'+resp[i].fecha_registro+
        '</td><td>'+resp[i].dias+
        '</td><td>'+resp[i].contacto_nombre+
        '</td><td>'+resp[i].modelo+
        '</td></tr>';
    }
    $('#body_table').html(html);
}`

Comment: gracias amigo me sirvió, ya podre seguir dandole

Comment: Me alegro. Animo!

Comment: tambien puedes hacerlo asi `if(!(data[i].fecha_registro))`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que tienes un tienes un json en forma de array y todo es un solo elemento, por eso el data.length te muestra todo el elemento, para mostrarlo debes iterarlo:

```
  for(var key in data)
 {
   console.log(key+" - "+data[key]);
   }
```

Comment: Lo imprime igual asi como puse arriba me imprime solo 1 letra y el numero por ejemplo
0 - 
1 - 
2 - [
3 - {
4 - "
5 - f